# CommonDialog on microsoft 365 Access working

Tags: ms-access-2003, microsoft365, common-dialog

I have a MS Access 2003 Database which uses the command "CommonDialog".

In this Database has access many computers with windows 10 and Microsoft 365.
Some computers can work with no issue but some other appear the error:

> "Object doen't support this property or method"

Do you know if there are any computer settings that can explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has restricted the support of `CommonDialog` from Windows 10, build 1809 on.

You must switch to the `FileDialog` property. Unfortunately, you will need Access 2007 for it. Here is how to use the `FileDialog`:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filedialog-property-8510b02d-e455-44a9-bf38-3787e6d5c8c1?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: I have read this but I am confused because some computers can work with no issues.

Comment: Then maybe these computers do not have the Windows Update.

Comment: In the same computer one user can work properly and another not.